# Solving the integral equation associated with Laplace transform

Tags: integration, analysis, laplace-transform

I am clueless on how to solve this integral equation:
$\lambda\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\exp\{-\lambda x\}dx=\sqrt{2\lambda}$, where function $f$ is a non-negative measurable function. And the result is $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}$. Any help would be appreciated.
I originally want to solve it through differentiating both sides, but I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*. Compare your integral equation with the definition of the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function),
$$
\Gamma(z)=\int_0^{\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t}\,dt\qquad(\Re(z)>0), \tag{1}
$$
from which follows
$$
\int_0^{\infty}x^{z-1}e^{-\lambda x}\,dx=\frac{\Gamma(z)}{\lambda^z}. \tag{2}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I see your solution is just a simple change of variable. Can I ask how can I adapt it to my general function $f(x)$? I don't see how I can remove the integral. Thank you.

Comment: Eq. $(2)$ implies $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2}x^{-1/2}}{\Gamma(1/2)}e^{-\lambda x}\,dx=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\lambda}}.$$The function $f$ also satisfies $$\int_0^{\infty}f(x)e^{-\lambda x}\,dx=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\lambda}}.$$What can you conclude about $f$?

Comment: Because the above equality holds for all $\lambda$, hence $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2}x^{-1/2}}{\Gamma(1/2)}$ almost everywhere right?